# Viewing data on browser

Tags: java, url, grails, urlconnection

i have a domain with fields like URL, lastModified etc. Now i want to view the information i get from this code  into the list page. How can i do tht

```
def url = new URL("http://www.google.com")
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection()
//  long contentLength = Long.parseLong(connection.getHeaderField("Content-Length"));
connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
connection.connect()
connection.getURL()
println("Date: " + new Date(connection.getDate()))
println("LastModified Date:" + new Date(connection.getLastModified()))
if (connection.responseCode == 200 || connection.responseCode == 201){
    def returnMessage = connection.content

    //print out the full response
    println "${returnMessage}";
    System.out.println(connection.getURL());
} else {
    println "Error Connecting to " + url
    println "Couldn't connect to url"
}
```

Comment: Where? in a page? your question is a bit vague. Please provide more details about the environment.

Comment: I mean i got this println thing for now jst to check if its working or not. now i want to populate these information in grails list.gsp page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your controller, you can use the `render` method,

```
render returnMessage
```

(see http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Controllers/render.html)

or pass it in a model to a gsp page and then print it from gsp,

```
return [returnMsg: returnMessage]

....(in .gsp)
${returnMsg}
```

(see http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#GSPBasics)